# Mongodb: match based on dynamic dates with $lookup

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection similar to this

```
[
  {
    "departure": "NYC",
    "arrival": "MIA",
    "date": "2018-11-22 12:20:00"
  },
  {
    "departure": "MIA",
    "arrival": "LAX",
    "date": "2018-11-22 19:20:00"
  },
  {
    "departure": "NYC",
    "arrival": "MIA",
    "date": "2018-11-22 23:20:00"
  }
]
```

I need to get all results that makes me a combination to reach from NYC, LAX.

So, it should get

**a.departure = NYC**

**a.arrival = b.departure**

**b.departure = LAX**

I was able to do this with a lookup (creating a self connection) + 2 matches:

```
{
  "$lookup": {
    "from": "routes",
    "localField": "arrival",
    "foreignField": "departure",
    "as": "step"
  }
},
{
    "$match": {
      "$and": [
        {
          "step.destination": "LAX"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
{
    "$match": {
      "$and": [
        {
          "departure": "NYC"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

The problem now is that I want to add a rule based on the date.
Date should not be longer than 3 hours.

I've tried with $match (in a lot of different combinations) without success.

```
{
    "$match": {
      "$and": [
        {
          "step.departure_date": {
            "$gte": "$date",
            "$lte": new Date($date.getTime() + 3 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Is this a "self join" on the same collection? What actually are you expecting as a result based on the data you provide? Note nothing you actually provide here seems to meet your criteria. Unless of course what you actually mean is the flights "connect" going to the destination. i.e from NYC to MIA then connecting to LAX as a destination from the MIA stopover. You really need to clear up that intent in the question

Comment: Yes, sorry if I didn't specify. Is exactly this, I need to get the connection to reach a location. So far, I was able to get this information but not to create a rule based on the time.

Comment: So ideal output would be the two documents showing starting at NYC, and then showing the "flight(s)" ( plural where a connection would be required ) which would be taken in order to arrive at the destination LAX within a certain time period? Also what do those dates actually look like in your database? Ideally you should use the [mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/) and be able to clearly see if they say `ISODate` or if they are just plain strings. Kind of "looks like" they might be "strings".

Comment: It's ISODate. Just checked

Comment: Found it!

{
  "$cond": [
    {
      "$lt": [
        "$step.date",
        { "$add" : ["$date", 21600000]}
      ]
    },
    "$$KEEP",
    "$$PRUNE"
  ]
}

Comment: That's not really the optimal solution, or even accurate since it could be possible there is more than one connection required. I'd "like to" show you something more optimal, but none of the data in the question actually has a destination date which would be greater than the departure ( or within 3 hours ) for a valid selection.